# Enviar email desde swift

Tags: ios, swift2, swift, email

Estoy haciendo una app en la que se van registrando usuarios y pueden interactuar con la app.

¿Se podría mandar un email desde `swift` cada vez que se registre un usuario o cada vez que consigan un récord de puntuación?

Comment: Sí se puede enviar email desde una App, sin embargo es un error hacerlo para lo que pretendes, ya que cada vez que quieras 'mandar un correo', se desplegará el controlador `MFMailComposeViewController ` con el 'email' configurado para que el usuario decida si lo quiere mandar o no, incluso con la opción de poder editarlo. Lo que necesitas es implementar la funcionalidad del lado del servidor a través de un `WebService`(SOAP  o REST) e invocarlo silenciosamente con la acción correspondiente para que este se encargue de mandar los correos de forma transparente para el usuario. Analízalo, Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que se pueden enviar correos (y además automáticos) :). En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28963929/1468942) proponen un código muy bueno para eso:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: ViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["nurdin@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Además, si quieres, tienes un tutorial [aquí](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/25/send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/).